# Does UdpClient.ReceiveAsync() method ensure datagram is received in one piece?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am quite new to socket applications. I have done a fair amount of research but have not been able to find a definitive answer. 
Pre-Edit: I am aware that UDP does not guarantee message delivery nor arrival order.

Assumption no package drop:
Whenever I send data using the following can I be sure that client has sent all the data, and server received everything in one piece. Or do I have to

1) On client side, check `sendData` variable to see if it is equal to the datagram`s size. If not equal then send the remaining data by offsetting as many as sendData.

2) On server side, check `readBuffer` size to see if it is equal to the datagram`s size. If not equal then send the remaining data by offsetting as many as sendData.

Client Side:

```
var client = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1",5001);
var sentData = client.Send(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5)
//can sendData be less than 5??
```

Server side:

```
var udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001));
var datagram = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
var readBuffer = datagram.Buffer;
//Can readBuffer contain less than 5 elements?
```

Comment: No you don't need to do that. But, you cannot be sure that data were sent, because udp is free to drop packets (if for example you are sending a lot in a tight loop, or sending too big packets).

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the comment. So just to be clear, assuming no data/package loss drop, server side receive the data in one datagram. I am at a loss why `Send` method has a return value for successfuly send data amount.

Comment: Yes, unlike tcp (which is streaming protocol), udp is message (datagram) protocol, and always delivers datagram as a whole. And my comment about send was related to your first question. Check result or not - you cannot be sure packet was sent, even if returns the exact number of bytes you expect. I mean it might not even leave your PC. So not worth checking even.

Comment: @Evk, thank you very much for the answer. I was under the impression that if I send a datagram of size of, let's say, 500 bytes, it is possible that it may reach the server side with less than 500 bytes and I had to do merging myself!

Comment: That's true for tcp but not udp. If you think about it, it cannot be any other way. Since order of delivery is not guaranteed in udp - there would be no way to reconstruct your packet if partial delivery were possible.

Comment: @Evk, I see thanks a lot